# Sending PHP GET data to server using Html links

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I haven't wrote PHP GET requests in a while. So I'm a little rusty. But how do I send GET data using an Html link. If I use jQuery's get method's I know how to do it, but I was just wondering if there is a simpler way using the href in Html or something similar.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you need?

Comment: Refresher:  `<a href="foo.php?param1=yes&param2=no">bar</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the parameters behind the url:

```
index.php?param1=yes&param2=no
```

Then you can read the variables over **$_GET**

```
echo $_GET['param1'];
```

But this are PHP basics. Perhaps you should read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) before.

In jQuery with an ajax request its the same. You can put your parameters behind the url.

```
$.get('index.php?param1=yes&param2=no', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

If you want to read all GET Parameters you can use a foreach loop.

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.":".$value;
}
```

Comment: Okay and I can variables as such: *index.php?userid=<?=$row->userid?>* ?

Comment: yes but i'am not a friend of open short tags but its working.

Answer (score 1):

The simple ways is,

```
<a href="page.php?string1=str&string2=str&string3=str"></a>
```

or a form doing,

```
<form action="page.php" method="get"></form>
```